# Why does moment.unix(0) returns 1 hour?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
var d = moment.unix(0);
console.log(d.hour());
```

I might be seeing this wrong but why is moment.unix(0) saying that is 1 hour?
Or I'm I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is your timezone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per MomentJS [Unix Timestamp (seconds) docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/) you are most likely in a +1 timezone

> Note: Despite Unix timestamps being UTC-based, this function creates a moment object in local mode. If you need UTC, then subsequently call .utc(), as in:
>
> `var day = moment.unix(1318781876).utc();`

Comment: We seriously need a canonical answer for Unix timestamps, since this sort of question comes up way too often.

Comment: Handling time is complex :)

Answer (score 0):

It is due to your specific timezone.  If you print out the moment object instance instead of just the date part you will see the following output:

> moment("1970-01-01T02:00:00.000")

In my case it's +2 because of my timezone.

If you instead do this

```
var d = moment.unix(0).utc();
console.log(d);
```

you will get

> moment.utc("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00")

which is the GMT (UTC) timezone.